# Paragraph is not respecting margin of heading

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to set up vertical rhythm on a page. But `p` is not respecting bottom margin of `h1`. Can someone explain me why?

Here is my code *(em units would be better but for the sake of simplicity I have used pixels )*:

```js
html {
  font - size: 18px;
  line - height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
  font - size: 30px;
  line - height: 1.5;
  margin: 4.5px 0 4.5px;
}

p {
  margin: 27px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>blaasdfasf</h1>
  <p>...</p>
</body>
```

Edit:

Here you can see what i mean:

[image: h1 preview]

[image: p preview]

The margin of `h` is ignored as you can se.

Comment: You need like: http://jsfiddle.net/mmokzwnn/ ?

Comment: Is the margin too much or not enough? Please create a fiddle.

Comment: If the margins collapse you can decide to switch to padding for one element (if it makes sense) or you can add a 1px height div wich will not allow the margins to collapse

Answer (score 3):

It's called "Collapsing margin", and there are a lot of topic about it. Basically the larger margin will count, it's very common. All you can do is increased the larger margin or change you HTML elements. You might like to read:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/
- [CSS Margins Overlap Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906640/css-margins-overlap-problem)
- [Margin doesn't work? Need space between two elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469784/margin-doesnt-work-need-space-between-two-elements)

---

A good solution is you create a container to the `p` elements into a `div` and put it in a `padding-top` property. With it, the content will have their own margin:

```css
html {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 4.5px 0 15px;
    overflow:auto;
}

#margin {
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>blaasdfasf</h1>
<div id="margin">
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Or simply apply the `padding` directly into the `p` element:

```
p {
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: Seems like this is the explanation, I needed, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. See the edit, I wrote a possible (and clean) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Margins collapse between adjacent elements. In simple terms, this means that for adjacent vertical block-level elements in the normal document flow, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero.

```
html {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1 {
font-size: 30px;
line-height: 1.5;
 margin:4.5px 0 4.5px;

}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mmokzwnn/3/

[Refrence](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/)

Comment: But i want that margin to be greater than 0. My problem is that `p` is not respecting bottom margin of 'h1'.

Comment: *P is not respecting bottom margin of  h1*  means actually what optput you want.

Answer (score 1):

W3C specification indicates that when the vertical margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero. Margin refers to another's element position not including its margins. You can sum padding but not sum margins.

```
 html {
          font-size: 18px;
          line-height: 1.5;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin: 4.5px 0 4.5px;

    }

    p {
    margin: 27px 0;
    padding 0;
    }
```

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/L0upwwcf/)

Comment: W3C specification indicates that when the vertical margins of two elements are touching, only the margin of the element with the largest margin value will be honored, while the margin of the element with the smaller margin value will be collapsed to zero. 
Margin refers to another's element position not including its margins. You can sum padding but not sum margins.

Comment: @kurenaiKunai you might want to include your comment as an edit into your answer. Provides a good explanation of the issue

Comment: @Anzeo Sure, will do.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but nowadays (in [modern browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) ) you can use the  `display: grid` css rule to make elements not overlap margin (see working code example).

```css
div:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  background-color: blue;
}
div p {
  background-color: white;
}
.display-grid {
  display: grid;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph block</p>
  <p>Paragraph block</p>
  <p>Paragraph block</p>
</div>
<div class="display-grid">
  <p>Paragraph grid</p>
  <p>Paragraph grid</p>
  <p>Paragraph grid</p>
</div>
```